# Why is my Pi running at 700MHz all the time?

Tags: overclocking

My RasPi is configured to 900MHz overclock using `raspi-config`, but it keeps running at 700MHz even under load. I have found [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/why-wont-my-raspberry-pi-overclock) already, and my system is also running with dynamic

```
for info in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_*
do 
  echo ${info}
  sudo cat ${info}
done
```

Output:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
900000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency
355000
```

Even when serving large files via SMB and running `apt-get update`, the frequency will stay at 700 MHz. Why?

Comment: Oh wow, now I saw it twice going to 900 MHz. I am using `watch -n 1 cat /sys/...` to monitor the frequency. Maybe I don't have a problem after all.

Comment: Doing lots of IO (serving files, downloading via apt) is not a processor intensive activity as the IO itself is a bottleneck -- meaning, the processor must wait on it, so while the system is busy working as fast as it can in one sense, the processor may be mostly idle.

Comment: @goldilocks: Well, smbd and ntfs-3g were producing close to 100% load, about 50% user and 50% system load each. I would have assumed that's enough, but maybe the system load was some kind of I/O waiting.

Comment: FYI here is an easier way to print your settings : grep "" /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even with dynamic frequency set, the Raspberry Pi has a very high default frequency scaling threshold.

To quote [this blog post on overclocking the Pi:](http://megakemp.com/2013/02/26/adventures-in-overclocking-a-raspberry-pi/)

> The ondemand governor used in the Raspberry Pi will increase the CPU speed to the maximum configured value whenever it finds it to be busy more than 95% of the time. That sounds fair enough for most cases, but if you’d like that extra speed bump even when the system is performing somewhat lighter tasks, you’ll have to lower the load threshold. This is also easily done by writing an integer value to a file (you can put the following for example in the `/etc/rc.local` startup file):
>
> echo 60 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand/up_threshold
>
> Here we’re saying that we’d like to have the Turbo Mode kick in when the CPU is busy at least 60% of the time. That is enough to make the Pi feel a little snappier during general use.

You can also set to CPU governor to performance instead of ondemand using a similar command:

`echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Performance will keep the CPU clocked at 100% all the time. Detailed information about the available modes can be found here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt

Comment: That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I made a small programm to automate the process 
Jonathan Milford described very good. It does this at every boot to make it persist.

[Link to my project](https://github.com/DavidM42/rpi-cpu.gov)