# Stuck Boot Reset | LSB: switch to ondemand cpu governor

Tags: boot-issues

**HW:** 
Raspberry Pi 3, 16 gig hard drive

**Relevant Output:**

```
Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Starting LSB: Autogenerate and use a swap file 
Starting LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor(unless shift key is pressed).. 
.. 
reset
```

**Description**

If I don't press shift on time my Raspberry Pi constantly resets itself. I used the Raspbian configured openhabian ISO image but my understanding is that this issue is part of Raspbian boot. SSH connection is not possible.

Otherwise image works fine.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue--all of a sudden--with a CM3 module. I don't believe we are on the latest updated version, but definitely Stretch.

Answer (score 0):

My raspberry pi has also suddenly starting going into a restart loop due to this.

I'm not sure why switching to the ondemand cpu governor causes a problem, but I've disabled it for now following instructions in this post: [How to change the default governor?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9034/how-to-change-the-default-governor)

You can do this by disabling the `raspi-config` service which, for me, didn't do anything other than switch to the ondemand cpu governor.  Here's how:

`sudo systemctl disable raspi-config`

Comment: for reference, the raspi-config mentioned above is not the cli tool used to change config - see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9034/how-to-change-the-default-governor#answer-9048