# Turbo doesn't kick in

Tags: raspbian, overclocking

I read this topic here:
[Why won't my Raspberry Pi overclock?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/why-wont-my-raspberry-pi-overclock)

but it seems a bit old to me and this line here

`echo 60 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand/up_threshold`

doesn't work because I dont have `cpufreq` inside `/sys/devices/system/cpu`.
I also tried

`echo 60 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/up_threshold`

but then I stop at missing `ondemand` folder in `cpufreq`.

Now my question stays the same as in that thread: Why does the Turbo not kick in?
I did `apt-get update` `apt-get upgrade` and `rpi-update` many times so I guess I have the newest Raspbian on my RPi Model B.

The Turbo only works if I set

`force_turbo=1`

or

`echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

which both always forces to stay in the overclocked state. I want to use my Pi 24/7 but only overclock when unter hard stress, like somebody playing on the Minecraft-server. The empty server idles a lot and could save the heat.

Any good solutions how I could set the threshold lower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved this. Made 2 mistakes. It should look like this:

```
# Here I forgot the quotes
echo "ondemand" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor

# This line should be AFTER the other one.
# If ondemand isn't set, you can't set it's threshold ;)
echo 95 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ondemand/up_threshold
```

If the script stumbles over an error it just stops! So check everything twice, guys! :D

Interesting is that most tutorials tell that the default-governor is "ondemand" but for me it is "powersaving". That's why it was always taking the default or _min values.

Now it perfectly goes to the set _min value of 300 MHz in idle or low usage like a running Minecraft-server with no players on it. And jumps up to 1130 MHz when the performance is needed. It also feels smoother :)